# show a custom link list in section header

Tags: module, ce-1.9.0.1, custom

I am a beginner Magento developer (I am currently using the 1.9.0.1 version). I am working on a project of web shop which has the need to display a series of custom link in the header section. I studied how to develop a custom module but I did not manage to display this list of links in my own template. Anyone can point me to some resource and/or give me some suggestions on how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.
I simply created a custom module whose Block class retrieves my array of custom links (according to the active language on the site)

```
class MyPackage_MyMenu_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    function getLinks(){
        return array(....);
    } 

}
```

Then I simply added my template file mymenu/index.phtml in the template folder of my own theme and the mymenu.xml in the layout folder of my custom theme. This is the mymenu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <mymenu_index_index>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="mymenu/index" name="mymenu_index" template="mymenu/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </mymenu_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Then, in the page.xml file of my custom theme I added this string under the header block:

```
<block type="mymenu/index" name="mymenu_index" as="mymenu_index" template="mymenu/index.phtml"/>
```

and finally in the header.phtml I was able to call

```
$this->getChildHtml('mymenu_index')
```

and I edited my mymenu/index.phtml to display the custom array returned by the Block class in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a cms block in your admin and then load it in header.phtml using:

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-custom-link')->toHtml();

you can also override header.phtml creating your theme variation, so theme upgradeability is preserved.

Comment: ok, but my shop works in many different languages.. I would like to avoid writing for each language a different static block. How can I read them from an array and show them in the header.phtml template?

Comment: If you are using store views for languages, you simply can choose "all store views" from the block. Can't you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Because each link has a different label (according to the active language on the site) and I would like to translate them on the fly instead of writing differnt blocks for each language

Comment: well, I don't understand very well your situation, but perhaps you should create a module for managing the links from the backend side. Then you could create a fronted template to show those links and for translations you could use a csv file.

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do but I did not manage to understand how I can add this template to my custom theme. Do you any tutorial which explains how to do it quite accurately?

Comment: unfortunately not, but you should create a block class into you module and then you can insert into your template using an xml code like this: <reference name="header">
      <block type="theme_path/class_name" name="your.custom.menu.name" as="yourmenu" />
        </reference>. Then in your layout file you can show it using: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('yourmenu');?>. Hope it helps to you